# Извлечение случайного значения из массива в Visual Basic 2010

Tags: массивы, php, visual-basic

Начал изучать Visual Basic и столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно сделать символьный массив и получить случайное значение из этого массива в переменную. Я только начал изучать Visual Basic, но на php это бы выглядело как:

```
$mass = array("lalka", "fsdfsd546", "heyt");//массив с названием $mass
$per = array_rand($mass, 1);//Извлекаю из этого массива одно значение в переменную
echo ($per);//Вывожу сообщение
```

Прошу написать как этот код будет выглядеть в Visual Basic.

Comment: начал изучать бейсик - закончи изучать бейсик.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поймите: Visual Basic и VB.NET - практически одно и тоже (синтаксис очень схож), отличие в том, что VB.NET[Visual Basic .NET] работает на платформе .NET Framework. Вы просите код на "Visual Basic 2010". Ппрактически, это он и есть, этот код будет работать и в "Visual Basic 2008", "Visual Basic 2005", и даже в "VS Express 2013 for Desktop"(который содержит Visual Basic). Почитайте спецификацию и определение Visual Basic 6/VB.NET/.NET Framework. Повторюсь, лучше учите C# (тоже на платформе .NET Framework)!

Сама функция:

```
Public Function RandomWord()
    ' Случайное число
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    ' Ваш массив:
    Dim massive() As String = {"lalka", "fsdfsd546", "heyt"}
    ' Случайное число, ограниченное количеством строк массива
    Dim random As Integer = rnd.Next(massive.Length)
    ' Вернуть результат:
    Return massive(random)
End Function
```

Затем используйте функцию, функция возвращает string:

```
Dim randomword As String = RandomWord()
```

И делайте вывод при помощи `MessageBox.Show(randomword)`, `Console.WriteLine(randomword)` или другими

Answer (score 0):

Вариант

```
Sub RndStr()
Dim ArrStr()
Dim sStr As String
    ArrStr = Array("lalka", "fsdfsd546", "heyt")
    Randomize
    sStr = ArrStr(Int((UBound(ArrStr) + 1) * Rnd))

    MsgBox sStr
End Sub
```